# search an array element in other 2d list and count sublists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new in python,
I have a list like : `A=['a','b','c']`
and a list like `B=[['a','c'],['a','c'],['b','b']]`
i want to have a list like `C=[2,1,2]`
C stores occurrence of sublists that each element of A comes in B
that means 'a' is in 2 sublists
'b' is in 1 sublist
and 'c' is in 2 sublists,
how can I achieve this?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over `b` and update a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for each sublist, using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to remove duplicates:

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['a','b','c']
b = [['a','c'],['a','c'],['b','b']]

counter = Counter()
for sublist in b:
    counter.update(set(sublist))
c = [counter[x] for x in a]

# result: [2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: i test it with an example that b was empty, i expected an empty list but it has values in it...

Comment: @Sahar If `b` is empty you get `[0, 0, 0]` as output. Is that not what you want? The answer you accepted gives the same output, by the way.

Comment: i have another problem, values will be multiple 2 after 2 times running the code...

Comment: @Sahar Which part of the code did you run twice? What was the result you wanted, and what was the result you got? Running this program twice doesn't change the output.

Comment: i found my mistake, i used this code for 3 arrays, with the same counter, after using counter1 , counter2, counter3 it works fine, thanks again

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sum`:

```
a=['a','b','c']
b=[['a','c'],['a','c'],['b','b']]
final_list = [sum(i in c for c in b) for i in a]
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop and compare in both lists

```
a=['a','b','c']
b=[['a','c'],['a','c'],['b','b']]
result = []

for letter in a:
    count = 0
    for l in b:
        if letter in l:
            count += 1
    result.append(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to construct `C`.

```
C = [sum(elem in sub for sub in B) for elem in A]
```

This has the same effect as using nested for loops:

```
C = []
for elem in A:
    sum = 0
    for sub in B:
        sum += elem in sub
    C.append(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try dict approach :

```
A=['a','b','c']

B=[['a','c'],['a','c'],['b','b']]

d={}

for i in A:
    for j in B:
        if i in j:
            if i not in d:
                d[i]=1
            else:
                d[i]+=1
print(d)
```

output:

```
{'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'a': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = ['a','b','c']
b = [['a','c'],['a','c'],['b','b']]

# initialise defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

# convert to sets for performance
a_set = set(a)
b_sets = list(map(set, b))

# loop through list of sets
for item in b_sets:
    for i in item & a_set:
        d[i] += 1

# retrieve counts in correct order
res = list(map(d.get, a))

print(res)
# [2, 1, 2]
```

**Performance note**

This may not matter, but the performance differential is interesting as it shows clearly the `Counter` overhead (4x slower).

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

a = ['a','b','c']
b = [['a','c'],['a','c'],['b','b']]

b = b*100000

def dd(a, b):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    a_set = set(a)
    b_sets = list(map(set, b))
    for item in b_sets:
        for i in item & a_set:
            d[i] += 1
    return list(map(d.get, a))

def counter(a, b):
    counter = Counter()
    for sublist in b:
        counter.update(set(sublist))
    return [counter[x] for x in a]

assert dd(a, b) == counter(a, b)

%timeit dd(a, b)       # 414 ms
%timeit counter(a, b)  # 1.65 s
```